# After setting up android-support-v7-appcompat R.java is missing

Tags: android, android-support-library, r.java-file, android-appcompat

I am trying to change my Eclipse project to make it backward compatible to Android 2.1.
I followed the instructions to set up the Support Library from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#)  but after I attached the Library project to my project, the R.java from the gen directory gone.

Plus I got some errors in the console, like:

```
[2013-09-02 00:08:26 - gitarshopAndroidClient] /usr/local/external/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2013-09-02 00:08:26 - gitarshopAndroidClient] /usr/local/external/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2013-09-02 00:08:26 - gitarshopAndroidClient] /usr/local/external/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: There are two options. The first is "Adding libraries without resources" and the second is "Adding libraries with resources". Which set of instructions did you follow?

Comment: Hmm, well the errors you show are clearly related to missing Android resources and that's why you don't have the R.java file as the build will abort when trying to create it if some resources can't be found. I had a dreadful time getting the v7 compat stuff working - it took a couple of hours fiddling around. In the end I think I closed my project, the library project then closed eclipse. I then restarted eclipse, opened the library project then my project and performed a Clean on both projects and everything returned to normal. A bit of a hack but it's all I can suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've already tried all of these without a luck :( The strange is that what I remove the Library reference, R.java appears again (after a Clean)

Comment: Are you using the v4 support appcompat stuff in your v7 support library project? You need to do that as far as I understand things as the v7 stuff isn't completely stand-alone. For instance my v7 library project shows android-support-v4.jar in both the 'Android Private Libraries' and 'Referenced Libraries' sections.

Comment: Correct. Both files are there.

Answer (score 20):

Okay, I figured out what was the problem.

The build target of my project was Android 2.1 (API 7).
I had to target Android 4.0 (API 14) at least to get rid of the warning message.

YOUR APP WILL STILL RUN ON Android 2.1 DEVICES! This is what I missed whan I set up the target wrongly.

Comment: Worked for me. One gotcha: Need to change target both in AndroidManifest.xml AND in project.properties

Answer (score 4):

Click in your project, select properties, select Andoid and do the same with the library to ensure that both have the same Project Build Target. Don't touch tha manifest sdk anything, as that will cause the error to reapear

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is to do the following:

- Right click on the `android-support-v7-appcompat` project and select
  Delete (just remove it from the workspace, don't delete from disk).
- Right click on your project and select Properties -> Android, and
  remove `android-support-v7-appcompat` from your references, and click Ok.
- Clean your project
- Then select File -> Import and re-import `android-support-v7-appcompat`.
- Then go back to Properties -> Android and add the reference again.
- Clean your project

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of new to Android development, but I found this solution:

1. If you want compatibility, first make sure you create your project with both the MinimunRequiredSDK, TargetSDK and CompileWith set to API7:Android 2.1(Eclair) at the "New Android Application" Eclipse's window.
2. Create the support Library project android-support-v7-appcompat, according to the guide provided by developers.android.com (http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#using-apis)
3. Add the support library to your project (Right button click on your project, properties, android, at the library frame). Notice that the R.java file is gone.
4. Go to your project's project.properties file and change the property called target to "Google Inc.:Google APIs:14". DO NOT change this attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
5. Clean your project. The errors are gone.
6. Run your project.
7. If you are not running your app on a real device, you'll always be asked to select a compatible device. Select one that runs Android 2.1 and enjoy.

OBS.: Due to this workaround, the annoying message "No compatible targets were found" will always appear if you are working with a Virtual Device. You can answer NO and select a device in the Android Device Chooser window. Highly recommended to choose one that runs Android 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Just click 
Project > Android > Fix Project Properties.

It worked on Eclipse Kepler and latest ADB version !

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jar (support v7) in libs folder of support v7 project in your project and add support version 7 as library project to your project

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the android-support-v4.jar from android private libraries
because it is already in android-support-v7-appcompat