# Android Support Library troubles with v7 appcompat using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library

New to the forums! :) Looking forward to participating here ;)
In the mean while, I AM STUCK!
I have just ran the sdk manager and have been up to date.

My program runs fine, but when I add in the support 7 appcompat something doesn't sit well. So I am here for here! Have spent two days trying to fix this:P

All I want app compat for is the halo themes lol so my app will run on pretty much all android versions
Thanks in advance guys & gals

I had to put picture links in pastebin because only allowed two links because I have no rep! :) 
http://pastebin.com/YfxzNv8U
One addition picture to show Package Explorer -> http://gyazo.com/b46ac98bacfbd051ecc1a2b3250bd68b
Thanks all

Alrighty
FIXED THE PROBLEM!
Could not answer own question because not enough rep!

Well I fixed it finally! Enough research :)

All I did was changed the Target API in project.properties from 7 to 19 and volla!

Comment: Your R.file is missing. [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563441/after-setting-up-android-support-v7-appcompat-r-java-is-missing) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563441/after-setting-up-android-support-v7-appcompat-r-java-is-missing

Comment: then delete question this not needed any more

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it finally! Enough research :)
[Giving up on support library v7. What did I wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950866/giving-up-on-support-library-v7-what-did-i-wrong?lq=1)

All I did was changed the Target API in project.properties from 7 to 19 and volla!