# R error when adding android support v7 appcompact library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I create a new android application minimum-target-compiler version is set to api level 10, deployed successful. But when i added support library to the project R.java disappeared in gen folder. [Error is, R can not be resolved  to a variable, please see the screenshot](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/5983a4c5-bfac-4fe5-8399-aad88a29864c/ec0f2210ef69845100edcf60bfc4f9c6). There is no error in xml. [I am getting error in console](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/d0ebaa8f-e37c-4b04-9bd1-c5e5c3504509/614ce4fb3659b505ccd48d460cb31623). I cleaned and build but did not work.

Comment: Try Clean & Build your project.

Comment: Consider including the image instead of linking to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389640

Comment: @Himani Agarwal, i have cleaned and build the project

Comment: Have you added the support-v4 library in your project ?

Comment: @Rethinavel Pillai, there is no "import android.R;" in the import statements.

Comment: @GrIsHu , yes i added the support-v4 library in your project.

Comment: show your build path. Make sure there is not two library added in your build path. The error may be occurring because of dependencies also.

Comment: @GrIsHu , thank you please see the  build path http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/c0552f88-bb84-4079-9a21-e66ede7743b3/131fdefa6ca3584fb7fa71002a4559f1  error not solved

Comment: @Shiva Its dependencies issue. Just remove the Android-Dependencies library and try to clean your project again .

Comment: @GrIsHu , i unchecked the Android Dependencies and clean and build the project but error did not disappear.

Comment: @Shiva Do not uncheck just remove it.

Comment: @GrIsHu , i removed as you said but after Remove it(Android Dependencies) appeaser again.

Comment: @Shiva Then do not add `andorid-support-v7-appcompat` in your build path as its already added in your dependencies.

Comment: @GrIsHu , i did not get you. Also see this http://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/3f08470f-f38d-4d40-a917-e9e41f995814/0993e814c699718d4f1602ff802388bd

Comment: I am saying that If dependecies library appears again then just remove your `andorid-support-v7-appcompat` from your build path which you have added.

Comment: Just try to change your api level to 4.0 or above and it will not show you this error.

Answer (score 0):

Set build target of your project was Android 2.1 (API 7). You have to target Android 4.0 (API 14) at least to get rid of the warning message.

Your app will still run on Android 2.1 devices.

Comment: Basically values-v14 used for version 14 and above.

Comment: i added android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" but not worked.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563441/after-setting-up-android-support-v7-appcompat-r-java-is-missing

Comment: Thank you more than 50% of your answer worked for me. problem solved

Comment: @Shiva Mine pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Kanwaljit Singh., Basically `values-v14` used for version 14 and above. Finally I found solution.

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:maxSdkVersion="19"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

And Project Build target to api-14. Finally clean and build the project. This solved in my case.